# To find an upper bound for binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Let $n$ and be a natural number and $1\leq k\leq n$. Then is it true that
$$\binom{en}{k}^k<\binom{n^2}{k}^k<n^{2k},$$
where $2<e<3$?

Comment: Pleas read https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Is $e$ the base of the natural logarithm?  Also, please explain the context in which this problem arose.

Comment: Is $en$ supposed to be a natural number?

Answer (score 1):

If the first two terms in the inequality are supposed to represent ($k$-th powers of) binomial coefficients, then the second inequality does not hold for *any* choice of $n$ and $k$. The first does hold for any choice of $n$, $k$ and $e$, simply because $en<n^2$.

Comment: $\( \frac{en}{k} \) ^k